# want to install on Dell netbook

Tags: dell, ubuntu-netbook

I have an old Dell Netbook10 with XP. I only have 1 G of memory. I would like to replace windows. What are the memory requirements for ubuntu? I have an external dvd drive for it, so how would I get it from my main computer to a bootable dvd/cd?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

The memory [minimum requirement](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for a normal desktop version is 512 MB.

On your main computer, you can download the [Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) iso image and create a bootable USB / DVD on it. Here is the instruction for [creating a USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). Don't forget you can try Ubuntu without actually installing it.

(USB is highly recommended as you might want to try some other light-weighted distro like Xubuntu, Lubuntu for your netbook, if it's slow with normal desktop edition on it. Please refer to the "Lightweight GUI alternative" section in the requirement wiki page.)

Comment: Thanks. Since I asked this I found Mint and Cinnamon that seem to be light weight. I made a flash of cinnamon and I will try that.