# How can I fix stucking error after some time?

Tags: 15.04

I got a notebook (Acer) is old, with a processor of 32-bits. I wanted to install the latest version of Ubuntu 15.04 and it opens, but after some time, it freezes. Nothing works, but is strange, for example: I open Firefox; it freezes, I open the terminal, it works but suddenly the thing freezes. Is very tiresome. I installed it in a partition of 36 gb from my pendrive. This happened  and I uninstalled it and re-installed but continues. Up to the only possible reason for me is that maybe this version is too new for my old PC (is like from the year 2008-2009, but I don´t want an older version of Ubuntu). But what i want is a possible solution, if there is.

P.D: Can it be a problem, maybe, with the hardware? Because I can run Windows 7 and is GNOME, so I don´t think it is the screen or sth. but also can´t be the RAM, I got a the version for my processor but I think it´s sth. with the OS. PLEASE HELP MEEEEE!!!! I REALLY WANT LINUX, at least there is another version I can use; like Linux Mint or RedHat or anything??

Comment: You can try to launch the program from a terminal (ctrl + alt + t), to see if there is any readable output, e.g. run `firefox` to start the browser. Or just try some light-weighted distro, please refer to this [article](http://askubuntu.com/questions/656282/).

Comment: give us more outputs like: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` and `sudo parted -l` just [EDIT](http://askubuntu.com/posts/687473/edit) your question and add it.